# Alexa intent slot AMAZON.LITERAL causes failed build

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to use the `AMAZON.LITERAL` slot type in my Alexa skill, but when I try building, I see this error:

```
Build Failed
Slot name "{What}" is used in a sample utterance but not defined in the intent schema. Error code: UndefinedSlotName - Thursday, Apr 12, 2018, 2:08 PM
```

The slot is named `What`, and I'm 100% sure it is defined. It builds successfully if I change the slot type to anything except `AMAZON.LITERAL`.

Here is my entire model:

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "chores",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Remember",
                    "slots": [
                        {
                            "name": "Who",
                            "type": "AMAZON.Person"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "When",
                            "type": "AMAZON.DATE"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "What",
                            "type": "AMAZON.LITERAL"
                        }
                    ],
                    "samples": [
                        "remember {Who} {What} {When}"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "types": []
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

This is the response I got from Amazon when I submitted the bug:

> We are not supporting AMAZON.Literal slot type anymore and we ask
>   developer to use customer slot type is they have some set of values
>   but if not then you can use AMAZON.SearchQuery where you will get the
>   whole query which customer is looking for and same you can use it in
>   you lambda function.

Comment: What language is the skill targeting? AMAZON.LITERAL is not supported in anything other than en-US from what I understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Here's the solution.

You need to define your Sample Utterances as

```
Remember {Neil | Who} {died | What} {yesterday | When}
```

Amazon made it mandatory to provide the example inputs along with your Slot names as AMAZON.LITERAL can take in a wide variety of values.

For more information, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249475/amazon-alexa-store-users-words?newreg=1237b52f049e408f9d7d1ee62c65ada6).

Comment: I don't think this is the case in the latest alexa dev console. This syntax also causes a failed build.

Comment: Mine got built yesterday as soon as I made the above changes. I think in your case, you have put all the slots together, side by side. How will Alexa differentiate?

Answer (score 1):

add some sample utterances in below format and it should work:

```
remember {Jack|Who} {bring fruits|What} {tomorrow|When}
remember {Mark|Who} {pay bills|What} {today|When}
```