# How to extract a custom slot from a user random input in Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot, jovo-framework

We have an intent with a custom slot called topic. The values of this slots could be for example:

```
Sports, Science, Cinema, TV
```

So our sample Utterances are like this:

```
{topic}
tell me about {topic}
what do you know about {topic}
i love {topic}
```

This works correctly if the users uses phrases like the ones in the sample utterances. But, is there a way to achieve the following?

We want the user to be able just to say anything between and after the `{topic}` . Something like:

```
{any} {topic} {any} - {what do you think about} {sports} {my friend?}
```

or

```
{any} {topic} - {i hate everything related with } {sports}
```

Is there a way for Alexa Skill to extract the `{Topic}` from any random phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reason to keep User's input organized (you just increase the probability of correct slot recognition) with sample utterances. But :) some time ago I've found this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53334157/2823106, actually it's a hack on Alexa but you can create the `catchAll` slot and try something like `{catchAll} {Topic} {catchAll}`. The problem I expect here is that Alexa won't recognize the Topic correctly but give it a try.

Comment: Does not work for me, finally i have found a workaround for the solution. It seems that with Amazon.Person allows you to catch all the utterance. Then when I have the utterance in the backend i search on the string the words that I need as the topic because all the topics are dynamic and i can set on the {locale}.json.

I use Amazon.Person because the Amazon.SearchQuery doesn't allow you to have the utterance like this : {topic}. It needs to have some statics words.